# When to use an interface rather than a superclass

Tags: c#

I want to create a number of ViewModels that have certain properties so I can use them polymorphically. Seems like the job for an interface:

```cs
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace Gui
{
    internal interface INavigable
    {
        /* The default navigation command for the ViewModel */
        ICommand MainNavigationCommand
        {
            get;
        }

        string MainNavigationCommandName
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
}
```

That works fine, though for any implementing class I need to not only assign the relevant properties, but also declare them.

```cs
using Gui.Utility;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace Gui.ViewModels
{
    internal class ExamsIndexViewModel : INavigable
    {
        // Declare INavigable properties
        public ICommand MainNavigationCommand { get; }

        public string MainNavigationCommandName { get; }

        ... other stuff ...

        public ExamsIndexViewModel(ExamsTabViewModel parent)
        {
            base.DisplayName = "Select Exam";
            ParentView = parent;

            // set the default command to be used in the template
            MainNavigationCommand = NewExamCommand;
            MainNavigationCommandName = "New Exam";
        }

        public ICommand NewExamCommand => new RelayCommand(_ => ParentView.NavigateToSelectTemplate());
    }
}
```

If instead of putting the properties into an interface I put them into a class and then derive my current class from that one, I can do the same thing but I don't have to go out of my way to declare the properties.

```cs
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace Gui.ViewModels
{
    internal class NavigableViewModel : ViewModelWithExam
    {
        /* The default navigation command for the ViewModel */
        public ICommand MainNavigationCommand { get; set; }

        public string MainNavigationCommandName { get; set; }
    }

    internal class ExamsIndexViewModel : NavigableViewModel
    {

        ...other stuff, and I don't have to declare the properties explicitly...

        public ExamsIndexViewModel(ExamsTabViewModel parent)
        {
            base.DisplayName = "Select Exam";
            ParentView = parent;

            // set the default command to be used in the template
            MainNavigationCommand = NewExamCommand;
            MainNavigationCommandName = "New Exam";
        }

        public ICommand NewExamCommand => new RelayCommand(_ => ParentView.NavigateToSelectTemplate());
    }
}
```

My question is, when/why would it be appropriate to use an interface rather than a class hierarchy?

Comment: An ```interface``` is bascially a contract. It provides extended functionality to the classes using it. That's like saying ```The cat IS ABLE to fly``` for ```class Cat : IFlyAble```. (note the ```able``` suffix). A class hierarchy is more like ```The cat IS an animal``` for ```class Cat : Animal```, basically _describing_ what an object _is_, rather than what an object is _able to do_.

Comment: Let's say you have interfaces `IA`, `IB`. You already have classes `A : IA`, `B : IB`. Now you need something that implements `IA` _and_ `IB`. Do you inherit from `A` and implement `IB` again? Or do you inherit `B` and implement `IA` again?

Comment: I'd usually reserve the base class for something that has some "meat" to the amount of shared code - not to save a bit of typing/clicking for two bog-standard autoimplemented properties. You only get to have one base class - save picking it until you need it.

Comment: To two of the points made above: i do get to have one base class, but if that base class can be a subset of a "higher" bass class, then why use an interface instead of that mediator class? In other words, why not have `Cat : FlyingAnimal` derive from `FlyingAnimal : Animal`  and inherit the `FlightSpeed` property, instead of `Cat : Animal, IFlyable` which has to also declare the property?